# Vertical Flight Paths

Tags: quadcopters, comparison

I've been searching around for software to allow a vertical flight plan. For example I want to flight 50m across a building at 20m AGL. Then drop 1m and fly back 50m. So on and so forth. I've read a bit into DJI, DroneDeploy, and Pix4D, but haven't been able to find anything. I've read something about double grids, but I believe that is for 3D models? I am not trying to capture a 3D model. I know that in at least Drone Deploy you can create multiple flight paths, but you have to land and restart for each altitude drop. I am also not taking any pictures. Looking for just the flight path. This could be done manually, but I'd prefer it to be automated.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a software called [UgCS](https://www.ugcs.com/) which I believe should fit your requirements. It allows you to create waypoints with precise location and altitude. There are options like [terrain following](https://www.ugcs.com/news-entry/true-terrain-following-available-for-professional-drone-surveys-and-inspections) which allows the UAV to maintain a relatively constant altitude above ground level, a [Facade scan tool](https://www.ugcs.com/news-entry/introducing-the-automatic-vertical-scanning-tool) which allows you to plan a flight path along a vertical plane at a certain distance from a wall, or there is the option to easily create custom waypoints with specific altitudes as shown in this flight path:

[image: flight path]

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do what you want with [iNav](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki), if you have a drone with a compatible flight controller that is. So you won't be able to use a DJI drone for example, and you will probably have to build it yourself.

Another option that I think should work is [Ardupilot](https://ardupilot.org/copter/index.html), wich also has fully autonomous capability with the option to create missions with multiple waypoints and varying height. Ardupilot also has a lot more prebuilt alternatives than are available with iNav.

Both of the options I mentioned above also works with sonar, to give a more accurate height measurement.

Ardupilot will probably be the best option for you, as iNav is less versatile and aimed more at towards people flying just for fun. Ardupilot is more mature and the only drawback I can become quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I went ahead an contacted the ArduPilot Facebook team and they said, "Unfortunately without removing the M210 autopilot and using a arducopter compatible autopilot we can’t be of much help here". So I will probably go with UgCS.